# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line when using custom view

Tags: android

The exception:

```
>         10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> 
>     10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error
> inflating class com.example.demo.ToDoListView 10-13 11:47:32.151:
> E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 10-13 11:47:32.151:
> E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 10-13 11:47:32.151:
> E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 10-13 11:47:32.151:
> E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 10-13 11:47:32.151:
> E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
> 10-13 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 10-13
> 11:47:32.151: E/AndroidRuntime(618):  at
> android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172) 10-13 11:47:32.151:
> E/AndroidRuntime(618):    at
> android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
```

This is my xml. It show no errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.example.demo.ToDoListView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
  android:textColor="@color/notepad_text"
  android:fadingEdge="vertical"
/>
```

I am trying to use it with a list adapter:

```
        aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.todolist_item,todoItems);
```

To Do list class:

```
public class ToDoListView extends TextView{
    private Paint marginPaint;
    private Paint linePaint;
    private int paperColor;
    private float margin;

    public ToDoListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ToDoListView(Context context, AttributeSet st, int ds) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
      Resources myResources=getResources();
      marginPaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      marginPaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_margin));
      linePaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
      linePaint.setColor(myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_lines));
      paperColor=myResources.getColor(R.color.notepad_paper);
      margin=myResources.getDimension(R.dimen.notepad_margin);      
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(paperColor);
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 0, getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight(), linePaint);
        canvas.drawLine(margin, 0, margin, getMeasuredHeight(), marginPaint);
        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(margin, 0);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }



}
```

Comment: I think "com.example.demo.ToDoListView" is not exact as it is in your custom class. Take you Package name from your AndroidManifest and class name from your java file.

Comment: Below that inflate exception should be the real cause of why it's happening

Comment: Chintant.. it didnt help.. see update

Comment: Post the code for the ToDoListView class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use the custom view in the xml layout that you need to modify this constructor:

```
public ToDoListView(Context context, AttributeSet st, int ds) {
    super(context);
    init();
}
```

to:

```
public ToDoListView(Context context, AttributeSet st) {
    super(context, st);
    init();
}
```

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Yes, otherwise the `LayoutInflater` will not find the constructor it needs to instantiate your view.

Comment: damn, it still throws that mistake

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice pattern I use for custom views which covers all scenarios.  Luksprog is of course correct but only covers one possible constructor.  For default views:

```
public MyCustomView(Context context){
   this(context, null);
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
   this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public MyCustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle){
   super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
   init();
}
```

Using this pattern, no matter which overload is used, super and init are always correctly called.  Your custom view will also render correctly in the UI previews assuming that onDraw can draw without external dependencies which are not resolvable pre-compile.