# Custom component inflates in App but not in Widget

Tags: android-widget, custom-controls, inflate-exception

## Background

I created a custom component to draw on top of an image. At this stage I am merely extending the view.

My primary intention was to create a Widget but could not get it to work. I tried to load the same component in a main Activity, it worked <kbd>Face Palm</kbd>.

To be clear I read [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872848/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-when-using-custom-view) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857260/inflateexception-with-custom-view) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933997/android-error-when-inflating-custom-view-in-xml) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22432901/android-view-inflateexception-issues-creating-custom-view) ... [many](https://static0.thequizimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/10-boring1.jpg) post on this topic. This is not a constructor issue.

## Symptom

When I load the component in a Widget, I get the following InflateException (no stacktrace).

```
2020-06-20 09:23:56.368 2602-2602/? W/AppWidgetHostView: Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(UserHandle{0}/ComponentInfo{com.package/com.package.WidgetProvider}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.package.MyView
```

## Code

The culprit class

```
@RemoteViews.RemoteView
public class MyView extends ImageView {

    public MyView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // Eventually we'll do something mystical here
    }

}
```

Here is the Widget Layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <com.package.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myimage"
        />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Note: if I switch com.package.MyView for ImageView, it works. See below (ImageView vs MyView)
[image]

## Question

How do I get this component to inflate correctly in the Widget?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately android does not support any descendants of the supported widget classes (`ImageView` included)
see note under "Creating the App Widget Layout" in the [Build an App Widget](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets) documentation page

Although , I did find that even though [TextClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock) is not listed under the supported layouts it is indeed supported on all the devices I tried on.
so maybe don't take that as an absolute fact.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Joe for pointing me away from the wrong direction.

## What worked

I basically had to customize the existing AnalogClock as follows

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <AnalogClock
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dial="@drawable/mydial"
        android:hand_hour="@drawable/myhour"
        android:hand_minute="@drawable/myminute"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is bare bones but it does the job.

## For the record

- AnalogClock is deprecated
- Extending the class (cf @Joe) does not work
- Copy pasting [AnalogClock source code](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-clock-widget-clock-design--mobile-11737) does not work.
- I recommend reading [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-clock-widget-clock-design--mobile-11737) about building your own AnalogClock widget

## Outcome

[image]

Comment: neat. on which versions did you try it on? and whats your "targetSDK" ? Im asking since AnalogClock is very much deprecated since API 23 (its a shame really). its cool that it still work though but I don't know if you can count on it for a published app.

Comment: On this specific Virtual Device I am using version 30. Looks like AnalogClock is still happily alive.